# Initial download of website into github

Tags: git, github

I have installed Git on my server and have successfully connected to Github.
I now want to download my website (that has already been developed) to Github in order to start version tracking. However, I am having a problem doing this.

I have signed up with Github and created a blank repository with a readme file.

I have logged into my server and created id_rsa.pub
I have copied the contents of id_rsa.pub using cat and put the key into my github account.

I now want to push my website to the repository on Github.

However, I can't seem to get it to work. Please could someone give me a walkthrough?
This is the initial download from the server to Github.

When I do

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get back:

> To `git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git`
>   ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to `git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git`
>   To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes (e.g. `git pull`) before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of `git push --help` for details.

When I do

```
git pull
```

I get back:

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for
>   details
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
>   with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream master <remote>/<branch>
> ```

Comment: There already is a walkthrough on github... did you do the SSH test, and did it return the desired success message? You say you can't get it to work, but what exactly are you doing that won't work?

Comment: When I do git push -u origin master, I get an error. failed to push some refs

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to:

`git pull origin master` to bring in changes from the server.

Then, `git push origin master` will work.

This is because you created a repository *with a readme file* and did a `git init` in your local copy instead of a `clone`.

Creating a readme file causes github to create a repository but then also push the readme to the repository - the server's version of your repository now has a commit that your local version doesn't have. So, before you can push your files to github, you need to bring your local copy up to date with github's.

Answer (score 1):

From the instructions that github gives you immediately after you create the repo:

> #### Existing Git Repo?
>
> ```
> cd existing_git_repo
> git remote add origin git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git
> git push -u origin master
> ```

Comment: I get this back: To git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: So did you do what the error message said and `git pull` before trying to push again?

Comment: I get this: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream master <remote>/<branch>

Comment: Sorry. I'm very new to Git. :)

Comment: if I do git pull git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git master, then I get - Merge branch 'master' and I don't know how to proceed from there...

Comment: You need to merge. `git merge`

Comment: When here: Merge branch 'master' of git@github.com:<github-username>/<github-repo-name>.git

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
# 
# First Commit  How do I execute git merge?

Comment: I can't seem to execute anything in the terminal

Comment: You need to provide a commit message. Git will not allow you to commit without one. There is a pre-filled merge commit message (which is fine). You're probably in vim right now, so press _Esc_ and then type `:wq` and press _Enter_. It sounds like you might benefit from taking a step back and starting with a [git tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+tutorial), or (if you're on a Mac) just using [Github for Mac](http://mac.github.com/).

Comment: That's great. Just to check, merging will not affect the files in the server directory. Don't want to delete everything :)